# windows azure verification with credit card

Tags: sql, wcf, azure

I'm student and i'm working on bachelor thesis. My app uses wcf and sql database. If I want to test the application I need to host it. I would like to host it on Azure, 90 free trial, but it needs verification with credit card. I'm worried about sharing my credit cards data. I want to ask you, if it's secure and after 90 I have to pay for it or not?
Thanks

Comment: You share CC details with other companies online, what's the difference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The billing and credit card information is hosted and stored by Microsoft themselves — you can look into the security of their practices in detail, but I am sure that they are okay. As long as you delete your database before the 90 days is up, you won't need to pay anything. You can still keep your subscription, just make sure that you aren't using any services. For peace of mind, check your billing on a daily basis and make sure that nothing is being recorded as running.

Comment: Is any alternative(free) instead of azure, where can I host wcf and sql database?

Comment: Not that I am aware of... particularly SQL. You can look at the free usage tier with AWS, but you probably have to give them credit card details too.